# PHP Recursive class returning NULL

Tags: php, class, recursion

Please friends, I need help for my code.

My `searchParent` function always returns NULL when it executes the `self::` more than once

```
class Search {
    public function listParents() {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM parents";
        return pg_query($sql);
    }

    public function searchParent($id) {
        $parents= $this->listParents($con);
        while ($r = pg_fetch_array($parent)){
            if ($id === $r['id_parent']){
                return $id;
            } 
        }
        $sql = "SELECT id_parent FROM parent WHERE id_parent = $id";
        $query = pg_query($sql);
        $result = pg_fetch_array($query);

        self::searchParent($result['id_parent']);
    }
}
```

My call, assuming there is the number 230 in the parent table

```
$id = $search->searchParent(230);
```

Comment: as it is recursive so it always it calls itself, and at a time the id_parent becomes null or zero, so it will return null to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bobble the **return** value of your function.

Before calling the `self::searchParent` you should add return statement:

```
return self::searchParent($result['id_parent']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the code by using `count` and `left join`:

```
 class Search
{

    public function searchParent($id) {
         $sql = "SELECT count(*) as cnt 
                                FROM 
                                     parents LEFT JOIN parent on parent.id_parent = parents.id 
                                WHERE 
                                      parents.id = $id";
         $query = pg_query($sql);
         $result = pg_fetch_array($query);

         return empty($result['cnt']) ? null : $id; 
    }

}
```