# Function works inconsistently

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am new to PHP. I have a function that works (the value printed to the screen from within the function is exactly what I expect), but only sometimes returns the answer (other times it returns `NULL`). I believe I have isolated the error to something involving my use of the `static` feature of PHP, but I am not sure how exactly I'm transgressing/how to fix it. I tried to work around it by creating a new non static variable to store the result, and that improved my code from always returning `NULL` to only sometimes returning `NULL`. The erring function is part of a larger suite of programs I wrote, so I'll include it and the testing function I use to check that it works.

---

#### probGen.php

```
<?
    require_once("randX.php");
    require_once("../displayArray.php");
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

    function probGen(array $arr, float $control = 0.01) 
/*
*   Generates a valid, random probability distribution for a given array of elements, that can be used in conjunction with "probSelect()".
*   Input: 
        $arr: An array of elements.
        $control: A value that decides how much mass is allowed to be unilaterally dumped onto one element. A high value would permit distributions where most of the mass is concentrated on one element. 
        If an invalid value is provided, the default is used.
*   Output: An associative array where the keys are the elements in the original array, and the values are their probabilities. 
*/
    {
        $control = ($control <= 1 && $control >= 0)?($control):(0.01);  #Use the default value if an invalid number is supplied.
        static $result = [];    #Initialises $result with an empty array on first function call.
        static $max = 1;    #Initialises $max with 1 on first function call.
        foreach ($arr as $value) 
        {
            $x = randX(0, $max);    #Random probability value.
            $result[$value] = ($result[$value] + $x)??0;    #Initialise the array with 0 on first call, and on subsequent calls increment by $x to assign probability mass.
            $max -= $x;     #Ensures that the probability never sums to more than one.
        }
        print("<br>sum = ".array_sum($result)."<br><br>");
        displayArray($result);
/*
*   After the execution of the above code, there would be some leftover probability mass. 
*   The code below adds it to a random element.
*/
        $var = array_values($arr);
        if($max <= $control)    #To limit concentration of most of the probability mass in one variable.
        {
            $result[$var[rand(0,(count($var)-1))]] += $max; #Selects a random key and adds $max to it.
            displayArray($result);
            print("<br>sum = ".array_sum($result)."<br><br>");  
            $sol = $result;
            return $sol;
        }
        else
            probGen($arr, $control);    
    }
?>
```

#### test.php

```
<?

    /*
    *   This file contains some functions that can be used for assigning probabilities to an array of elements or selecting an element from said array with a given probability.
    */
    
    require_once("../displayArray.php");
    require_once("confirm.php");
    require_once("randX.php");
    require_once("probGen.php");
    require_once("probSelect.php");
    
    $test = ["California" => 0.37, "Florida" => 0.13, "New York" => 0.28, "Washington" => 0.22];
    $testX = array_keys($test);
    
    var_dump(probGen($testX));
    
    /*for ($i=0; $i < 100 ; $i++) 
    { 
        print(var_dump(confirm(probGen($testX))));
    }*/
    
?>
```

Screenshot of `probGen()` working as intended:
[image]

Screenshot of `probGen()` failing:
[image]

From testing I've been able to determine that `probGen()` fails if the recursion occurs more than once.

Comment: You need to return the probGen result in your else block.

Comment: @aynber I don't understand how that works? In my (admittedly limited) understanding `else` transfers control to `probGen()`, so nothing after the function call would get executed? Furthermore, shouldn't the completion of the program occur in the if block? I think it may be because I didn't decrement `$max` after the final assignment, so it would create an indefinite recursion/otherwise fail. I'm on mobile now, and would try that fix once I get back to my laptop.

Comment: Instead of thinking of it as the same function, think of it as different functions. You call function 1, which will either return a value or call function 2. Function two returns a value to function 1, but function 1 never actually does anything with the response, so it gets lost in the ether. Doing `return probGen(...)` will return the response from the recursive function. Calling one function from another doesn't transfer control. Another way to look at it is you call friend #1 with a question. They don't know, so they call friend #2, and then have to call you back to tell you the answer.

Comment: @TobiAlafin adding `return` would return the result of each recursive call of `probGen()` to the one before, which will eventually return it to the initial function call.

Comment: @aynber, Lewis thank you very much. I understand where I went wrong. Please format your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@aynber** comment (all credit to him I just wrote that so this post will have an answer).

When calling the recursive call you should add `return` (at the last line) in order to bubble the **return value** of `probGen` function as `return probGen();`

Generally speaking, having PHP return `NULL` sometimes may use as hint to case when non value is being returned.

Can see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050619/php-recursive-class-returning-null/52050707#52050707) question with same issue.